# Video driver "tested" disappeared among "Software and updates"/"Additional drivers" options

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, proprietary

Hi: I have an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2 video card, Kde 5.27.4 installed on Ubuntu Studio 23.04 and the pc is a notebook;
I selected the "nvidia-driver-530 (proprietary)" driver, which is the most recent one among the options proposed by the system: the fact is that previously I had one of the drivers (the most recent one) marked with "(proprietary/tested)": now no driver has this marking, and the "Software and updates"/"Additional drivers" program tells me that "this device is using an alternative driver": how can I make the "tested" one reappear?
I seem to remember I've activates the repositories for the graphics drivers.

Thank you.
Montyzoom